# An error of Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint that cannot be recreated

Tags: sql-server

I have a question of an error of Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint that cannot be recreated as follow:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__FPIO_Log__3214EC27EB54FBE5'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.FPIO_LoginActivity'. The duplicate key value is (1).

The action is to populate FPIO_LoginActivity with a select query. There is only one row inserted successfully. I cannot find any row with duplicate ID from data source. I tried to execute the statement itself rather than running whole script, and it passed without any problem. 71112 rows are inserted successfully. So I cannot recreate the problem. I cannot find any other code refers to this table, nor update or insert this table.

Can anyone give me a suggestion about possible cause?

This is my code:
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT  [dbo].[FPIO_LoginActivity] ON;

```
insert into [dbo].[FPIO_LoginActivity](CreatedBy, CreatedOn, HostName, ID, 
IpAddress, IsDeleted, IsSuccessful, LoginDate, ModifiedBy, ModifiedOn, 
UserID, UserName)
select case when fla.CreatedBy not in (select u.ID from [dbo].[User] u) 
then 1 else fla.CreatedBy end CreatedBy, fla.CreatedOn, fla.HostName, 
fla.ID, fla.IpAddress, fla.IsDeleted, fla.IsSuccessful, fla.LoginDate, 
case when fla.ModifiedBy not in (select u.ID from [dbo].[User] u) then 1 
else fla.ModifiedBy end ModifiedBy, 
fla.ModifiedOn,
case when u.ID is not null then u.ID else null end UserID,
fla.UserName 
from  [SWIMS13].[dbo].[FPIO_LoginActivity] fla left join [SWIMS13].[dbo]. 
[User] u
on upper(fla.UserName)=upper(u.UserName)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT  [dbo].[FPIO_LoginActivity] OFF;
```

Comment: Show us the statement(s) you're running here. We can't debug a statement if you don;t give us said statement. Clearly you're trying to `INSERT` a duplicate key here.

Comment: This kind of error is ALMOST ALWAYS the result of a duplicate row being returned by your SELECT query. Start there. The table source may not have duplicate rows, but if your SELECT query is doing joins of any kind, it's quite possible a row is being duplicated, which then results in the error on attempt to insert.

Comment: I have checked my query, it does not generate any duplicate keys

Comment: Given your query is copying data from another database the way it is I'm assuming you have a prior statement that deletes or truncates dbo.FPIO_LoginActivity... could that have failed at some point leading to duplicate rows?